# Is this view on homosexuality is correct?

Tags: homosexuality

One of my friend things this about homosexuality. I am quoting his statement.

"Homosexuality is as haram as music. Haram literally means haram. Thus both of these are liable to same punishments.
Would you boycott music? I know you can’t, me neither. So you are bound to do a haram thing and recommend others to stop doing or even supporting other haram things? how’s is that supposed to work?
However Islam has a nicer way to deal with complex arguments.

“The servants of the All-Merciful who walk humbly upon the earth and when the unruly taunt them, they reply ‘peace’ “ (25:63)

So if you ever come up to a person who has different beliefs or has different opinions over same beliefs or you ever taunted by someone who disbelief the stuff you belief, try to reply peace. YOU DON’T HAVE TO RAGE BRO."

I am straight and
I don't support LGBTQ. What kind of behavior should I have done towards people who are homo? Should I raise my voice strongly and say that it's haram in Islam (although everyone is not Muslim). Or should I avoid the whole thing and leave everything as they are?

Comment: "Haram literally means haram. Thus both of these are liable to same punishments." I guess your friend does not understand the concept of severity. Two things can be haram e.g. murder and stealing *and* one can be more severe than the other thus having a greater punishment.

Answer (score 3):

Your friend does not understand the concept of severity as I already commented. Some sins are bigger than others.

Murder and stealing are both sinful. However, one is punishable by death and the other only by cutting of the hand.

Advising people who have homosexual relations is the example a prophet himself set in the Quran. Allah says:

> And [mention] Lot, when he said to his people, "Do you commit immorality while you are seeing?
>
> Do you indeed approach men with desire instead of women? Rather, you are a people behaving ignorantly." (27:54-55)

People mention this verse a lot without looking at the text itself:

> The servants of the All-Merciful who walk humbly upon the earth and when the unruly taunt them, they reply 'peace'. (25:63)

Why do you think the unruly taunt them? Do you think the disbelievers of Makkah just randomly started taunting Muslims?

They taunted them because the Muslims preached to them and advised. In response to this taunting after advice, we should say 'peace'. But, you do have to preach and advise first.

The verse isn't an escape from the obligation of advising. It is how to deal with the adverse reaction that might come from advising people.

Allah says in the Quran:

> And let there be [arising] from you a nation inviting to [all that is] good, enjoining what is right and forbidding what is wrong, and those will be the successful. (3:104)

As for whether you should raise your voice strongly, you should figure out the best way to advise. But, always ignoring is not supported by Islam.

Answer (score 0):

The values we hold as Muslims are not determined by prejudice or our personal considerations but by a system placed by Allah (swt) through his Messenger (saw). Islam's prohibition of any indecent sexual act is clear... Therefore, it is expected of a Muslim to say the truth the way it is. This does not mean he attacks or raises his voice because the truth is in the convincing evidence. Read this answer on how Islam Muslims should address the issue of Homosexuality [What is the best way for Muslims to Address the Issue of Homosexuality](https://www.islamiqate.com/3145/what-the-best-way-for-muslims-address-the-issue-homosexuality.)